# Put JqueryUI Dialog Box in a Table Cell

Tags: html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

So I want to do something like this:

Some Picture

So that the dialog is always exactly 500 pixels away and in the appropriate area. Usually I would just stick it in, but it looks like converting it to a dialog box with $("#thejquerydialogbox").dialog()

always puts it in a random place on top of all other elements of my page. How do I accomplish getting it into the area I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can put it in a table cell, as it by definition is on top of all other elements. That said, you **can** define where it should appear by calling it with a position:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-position

Call it with the x and y coordinates of where you want it to appear